# How to ensure valid dependency graph within my application architecture

Tags: javascript, node.js, architecture, backend

**tl;dr:**

Is it possible to reinforce / guarantee (using a library or something else) that a .js file will only have access to a specific subset of modules?

For instance: If the .js file is on the folder `/controllers` it's only allowed to have access to specific global modules (ex: `express`) and import from specific folders (ex: `../repositories`). Anything outside this list is not allowed

**Rationale behind:**

In a large project with many developers it is almost inevitable that someone will invade layers. For example: within an action of an MVC controller, access the database via [db driver / SQL without](https://mherman.org/blog/postgresql-and-nodejs/) going through a repository or a more [sofisticated abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833080/executing-sql-queries-in-a-controller-action).

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pg = require('pg');
const path = require('path');
const connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL;

router.get('/api/v1/todos', (req, res, next) => {
  const results = [];
  pg.connect(connectionString, (err, client, done) => {
    const query = client.query('SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id ASC;');
    query.on('row', (row) => { results.push(row); });
    query.on('end', () => {
      done();
      return res.json(results);
    });
  });
});
```

This very basic example, just to illustrate the problem. In fact, in a multi layered / multi modules system, things are actually a bit more complicated and it's quite common to see invalid dependency graphs appearing as the project grows.

I know that part of the problem is solved with team training, but I wonder if there is any way to systematically reinforce this. Maybe something close to [no-restricted-imports](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-imports) or [no-restricted-modules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-modules) on ESLint.

edit:

- ESLint references.

Comment: There may be some static analysis tool that would help, but honestly this is what code reviews are for...

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, I'm aware of the others team/people/process solutions. What I'm looking for is a software solution for this, given it seems pretty feasible.

Comment: A hierarchy of modules would help. If `@foo/feature-module` depends only on `@foo/repositories` that exposes allowed API, a developer won't be able to use `pg` directly - it's not among `@foo/feature-module` dependencies. As it was said, this is a task for code review. If some developers are unable to provide quality code, they likely shouldn't be able to commit to a project out of control.

Comment: > a developer won't be able to use `pg` directly 

@estus how how do you do that without code review?

Comment: The project has `@foo/repositories` in `dependencies`. Not `pg`. A dev isn't able to use `pg` without adding it with `npm i pg`. There's no way how you could enforce a project to not use `pg` because `pg` inside `@foo/repositories` and `pg` in project can refer to 2 different packages because of different version constraints. If any dev is allowed to add arbitrary dependencies to the project, this would be my primary concern, and it can be solved with a single line in guidelines.